# how can i access iphone contacts from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, addressbook, messageui

I want to send a SMS from my application. For that,i use `MFMessageComposeViewController` and **"messageui.framework"** and is working greatly. But for that i gave the number of receiver in code. Actually,i want to add contact from phonebook. How can i get the desired contact in my application at the time of sending sms using `MFMessageComposeViewController` ?

Suppose my code is below and i dont understand how can i give contact number from my contacts in picker.recipients.Please help me as i want to select the contact number from contacts to send sms from my application.

```
-(void)ComposerSheet 
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1234567890"];  
    picker.body = @"I am at %@";

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are using `MFMessageComposeViewController`, then it automatically gives the link of contacts. So no need of `AddressBookUI` Framework required in this case. In `MFMessagecomposeViewController`, contacts have to be added by clicking the "+" button on the right side of the add recipients field.

Answer (score 2):

There are two frameworks for this. Address Book UI gives you some views to use. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html

Address Book doesn't, but it still gives you programmatic access to the address book.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007212